# Ionic passing complex object to a Modal via NavParams

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic page and I am trying to pass an array of an object to my Modal page:

```
export class SelectAddress{
    constructor(
        public id : string,
        public number : string,
        public line1 : string,
        public postcode: string
    ){}
}
```

I am attempting to do this via the following code on my Ionic page:

```
  let modal = this.modalControl.create(SelectAddressPage, {addresses: this.addressResult as Array<SelectAddress>});
  modal.present();
```

On the Modal, I am attempting to retrieve the data with the following code:

```
constructor(
          public platform: Platform,
          public params: NavParams,
          public viewCtrl: ViewController){
this.addresses = params.get('addresses') as Array<SelectAddress>;
```

Subsequently on attempting to loop through the results I am getting an error message:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object
>   '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to
>   Iterables such as Arrays. Error: Cannot find a differ supporting
>   object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding
>   to Iterables such as Arrays.

It seems I can happily send primitive data types like integers and strings but anything more complex doesn't seem to work here.

Initially, on my ModalControl I attempted to inject in my AddressService to retrieve the data but when I attempted this, the dependency injector failed to inject the dependency.

Should I be trying to send a complex type via the navParams or should I be trying something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error I was getting was simply because the type I was trying to cast to didn't match up because I had referenced the wrong variable.

This is what I meant to do:

```
let modal = this.modalControl.create(SelectAddressPage, {addresses: this.addressResult.addresses as Array<SelectAddress>});
```

**this**.**addressResult**.**addresses**, not **this**.**addressResult**

I was being very silly.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are trying to use a typescript `class` for type assertion. To ensure a variable is of a certain type by either the older type assertion (`let x = <Type> getX();`) or newer `as` operator (`let x = getX() as Type`) you need to define an `interface` or a `type`:

```
export interface SelectAddress {
  id: string;
  number: string;
  line1: string;
  postcode: string;
}

export type SelectAddress = {
  id: string;
  number: string;
  line1: string;
  postcode: string;
}
```

Typescript types in general are a compiletime construct and do not exist at runtime so when you run you application you are in fact always passing a javascript primitive type.

Comment: Hi David, I created the interface just as you have and when I am casting, I have specified the interface type. On running the application, unfortunately I get the same error message. Any ideas? 
For example, I have, "this.addressResult as Array<SelectAddress>"

Comment: Actually I'm just being an idiot. The correct code I needed was this.addressResult.addresses as Array<SelectAddress>. Thank you for the help anyway, I can't believe how silly I was being. It worked fine even when using the class.